# simple approval workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a simple "out of the box" approval workflow attached to a sharepoint calendar that kicks off when a user creates a new calendar item. I want the calender to only show items that have been approved via the workflow. Therefore, I created a lookup field on the calender that pulls the "Outcome" field from the workflow task list. I thought I could easily filter on the "Outcome" field by "begins with Approved" but I get the following error message:

The filter type you selected cannot be used with this type of column.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SharePoint error message:

> The filter type you selected cannot be
>   used with this type of column. You can
>   apply the 'begins with' operator only
>   to columns that have the type **Single
>   line of text**, **Multiple lines of
>   text (without rich HTML)**, or
>   **Choice**. Specify a different operator for the filter or change the
>   column type. You can then attempt to
>   create the filter again.

So you can:

1. Change your column to **Single line
   of text**
2. Or simply use **Equal
   to** operator as it does work with
   Lookup columns.